# derivative under integral intuition

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, intuition

> let $f(x,y)$ continuous in $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $ continuous in $[a,b] \times [c,d]$, define $$F(y) = \int_a^b f(x,y)dx$$
>   then $$F'(y) = \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) dx$$

Can you explain the intuition behind this rule, in terms of geometry for example, or how did Leibniz  came up with this rule?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To understand some formulas from calculus intuitively, we could try to interpret the notions in discrete ways.

For $y\in [c,d]$, the values

$$F(y) = \int_a^b f(x,y)dx$$

denote the areas of the slices (integrals along the x axis) specified by $y$:

[image: F pic]

To measure the difference between each two adjacent areas (discrete analog of $F'(y)$), one tried to draw all the little changes in height between the slices.

[image: F' pic]

In the picture above, pink arrows are grouped by their colors. Each group of pink arrows indicates the change in area between each two adjacent slices.

On the other hand, every single pink arrow can also be regarded as the partial derivative $\frac\partial{\partial y}f$ at each point $(x, y)$.

Thus, summing up a group of partial derivatives means measuring the difference between two areas.

[image: F' pic]

Comment: very nice illustrations.

Comment: Thank you !! , and your illustrations are great !

Comment: Congratulations, very insightful.

Comment: Although I can feel Cauchy rolling in his grave, this is the first time I have actually understood this concept. Brilliant

Comment: What a wonderful explanation!

Comment: @autodavid As others have pointed out the illustrations are excellent. Isn't though the derivative the rate of change of area and not just the area difference between adjacent slices?

Comment: @user599310 You're right. If I wanted to use discrete analogue, I should have wrote down some difference quotient, or should have specified the distance between the slices to be 1. Thank you for pointing out the subtleties.

Answer (score 0):

You could see it as an alternative version of Schwarz's theorem. When you have a map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ you would like to get to the same value if you first walk along $x$ and then $y$ as well as the other way around $y$ and then $x$.